# JMeter POSTing large files is slow

Tags: jmeter

I'm using JMeter to load test a service where I am POSTING large messages (2 - 20MB).  The existing HTTP sampler can be setup to POST the contents of a file, but it loads the file each time which makes it hard to send a decent load as it takes several seconds just to load the file.

Ideally it would load the files once into memory the first iteration.

I thought I could setup a BSF sampler using Groovy.  But the BSF sampler seems to re-compile the script each time so I don't have a way to just load the file once.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a discussion on this problem: [Google Groups topic](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jmeter-plugins/VDqXDNDCr6w/overview)

As a result, I modified Raw Request and it does efficient large file POSTs

Comment: I haven't had a chance to test this out.  I'll mark it as "the answer" when I do ... but I'm not sure when that will be.

Comment: Here's download for Raw Request plugin: http://code.google.com/p/jmeter-plugins/downloads/list

Comment: I don't see any plugin with the name raw request?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the **recompile** problem, since JMeter 2.8 and with upcoming 2.9 version

you will be able to cache (+compile) the script when using [JSR223 Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler)+ Groovy.

This will become the most optimized way of doing scripting.

See this for an example:

- http://www.dzone.com/links/r/jmeter_how_to_run_a_sampler_with_a_certain_percen.html